# Puppeteer Error no node found for selector

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am having trouble getting a selector on an HTML page this selector is not dynamically loaded. I'm able to run the application on local Windows/Centos 7 distro, but when I tried on my Centos 7 droplet this error occurs.

`Error: No node found for selector: .gcw-origin
    at assert (bin/glocities-app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:278:11)
    at Frame.type (bin/glocities-app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:803:5)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (bin/glocities-app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:144:27)
    at Page.type (bin/glocities-app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:1012:29)
    at getFlightData (bin/glocities-app/app.js:119:16)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)`

Here is some of my code:

```
`const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

await page.goto("https://www.expedia.com/flights");

await delay(20000);

await page.waitForSelector(".legal");

console.log("Legal Loaded");

console.log("Origin Loaded");

await page.type(".gcw-origin", orig.toString(), { delay: 100 });//Orig is your origin`
```

Comment: Try to wait for it to appear first: 

await page.waitForSelector(". gcw-origin")

and then type into it.

Comment: Interesting `{ TimeoutError: waiting for selector ".gcw-origin" failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded`

Comment: Did you consider that class never appearing? Why don't you get a screenshot before and after that line so that you see if it's really there?

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagescreenshotoptions

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem I can see what happening now time to re-write my code.

Comment: Not to worry, happing coding.

Answer (score 0):

I met the problem like you after a long time to fix this error, I add this code before make 
 activity with selector:

```
await page.waitFor("#yourSelector");
```

And it work. Hope it can solve your problem